# Blockquote styling breaks float-left div?

Tags: css

I have two divs on a page. Div #1 is floated left and contains an image and some text. The text in div #2 wraps around it nicely, as I expect. But when there's a blockquote with some styling in div #2, the styling extends into div #1. This isn't what I want.

I'm sure I'm missing something super basic, but I can't figure out what it is.

In this sample, I don't want the red going into the gray.

```css
.floatl {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #CCCCCC;
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

blockquote {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  border-top: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="floatl"></div>
<div>
  <p>This is some text here.</p>
  <blockquote>This is a quote.</blockquote>
</div>
```

I'm looking to either a) get div #2's non-text content to respect div #1 or b) discover another way to float div 1 to the left.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Instead of describing code verbally just include the code.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the divs in a new div and apply `display:flex` so it will become the flexbox container.

```
.new-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

Your main content, which is now a flex item along with the `.float1` div, will want to shrink up. I gave the content div a class and told it to grow to fill the rest of the flex container:

```
.main-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Remove the `float` and now you are good.

```css
.new-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.floatl {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #CCCCCC;
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.main-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

blockquote {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
  border-top: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="new-wrapper">
  <div class="floatl"></div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <p>This is some text here.</p>
    <blockquote>This is a quote.</blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! -- I would like to have the text in .main-content wrap around .floatl when it gets to the bottom of .floatl's 200px height. Unless I'm missing something, with a flex solution, they are now two columns of content running down the page.